# Socket.io Java Client version 1.0.x

Tags: android, sockets

i am building an app in android and requires to connect with sockets at some point. I am using socket.io-client.java 0.3.0 jar file. But it requires 1.0 version i guess but can't able to get it on net.

And by using jar file I cannot find Emitter.Listener() and on functions.

Waiting for help!

Comment: It seems that 0.3.0 is the latest version of this library. Why do you think that 1.0 is required?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is only using v1.0 then I guess this is your answer: https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java